Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{(\sin^2 x-16)(\sin x-3)}dx$
I first tried to integrate using Integration by partial fraction. Then I got $\frac{\sin x}{(\sin^2 x-16)(\sin x-3)}=\frac{1}{2(u-4)}-\frac{1}{14(u+4)}-\frac{3}{7(u-3)}$ where $u=\sin x$ but don't know how to progress further.......

Use half angle formulas.

Have you tried this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

I haven't tried the half angle formula yet let's see where it gets me off. Is there any other approach that you think might solve this more cleanly?

Use the tangent half angle substitution plus partial fraction decomposition.

Long comment not an answer! to add more details since these comments are enough to solve your problem. ...
Partial fraction plus Half angle substitution  or direct use this formula.
\begin{align}
\int{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sin\left(x\right)+a}}=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a\tan\frac{x}{2}+1}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)+C.
\end{align}
EDIT:
Note $a=1$ might be special, no other restrictions.

The alternative form is
$$
\int{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sin\left(x\right)+a}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}\ln\left(\frac{a\tan{\frac x2+1-\sqrt{1-a^2}}}{a\tan{\frac x2+1+\sqrt{1-a^2}}}\right)}
$$
by $\arctan x=\frac1i\ln\sqrt{\frac{i-x}{i+x}}$,
if $a=1$ then
$$\int{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sin\left(x\right)+1}}=\frac1a\tan(\frac x2+\frac\pi4)$$


Be careful to note that this formula is only valid when $|a|>1$.

Your method is fine but there is likely no way to avoid the tangent half-angle substitution considering the integral's exact value is a linear combination of irreconcilable $\arctan$ expressions.
The typical application $t=\tan\dfrac x2 \implies \sin x=\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}$ yields
$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{t\left(1+t^2\right)}{\left(3-2t+3t^2\right) \left(4+7t^2 +4t^4\right)} \, dt$$
while a related substitution $\tau=\tan\left(\dfrac\pi4-\dfrac x2\right)=\dfrac{1-\tan\frac x2}{1+\tan\frac x2}\implies\sin x =\dfrac{1-\tau^2}{1+\tau^2}$ produces the slightly cleaner*
$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{1-\tau^4}{\left(1+2\tau^2\right) \left(15+34\tau^2+15\tau^4\right)} \, d\tau$$
Either way, partial fraction expansion is the next step, but* the denominator in the latter integrand admits a simpler factorization (the quadratics are free of linear term) and subsequent PFE and antiderivatives.
